# Mobile data is disabled, but some data is still transmitted

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, mobile-data

First of all, I've read several similar questions here, but they are either not related, or require root access (Droidwall and stuff).

I received my Google Nexus 4 a week ago, and enjoying it so far. One thing is bothering me though.

I have access to Wi-Fi pretty much whenever I need it, so I'd like to disable any mobile data usage, at least until I figure out a nice data plan.
So the first thing that I did was unchecking `Mobile Networks > Data Enabled` and `Data Usage > Mobile Data` (I believe, these are the same thing). Now, the usage graph is empty. However, my carrier's report shows several records (6 in 2 days) of low mobile internet usage rounded to 100kb each. Cost-wise, it is equal to about 1 minute of talking.

I could probably live with that, but I have a trip to another city in a few days. If it happens while I'm in roaming (although `Data Roaming` is also unchecked), it will become much more expensive.

And so, the question is: how do I block mobile data for sure and let all the apps only use the Wi-Fi connection?

Non-rooted Google Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.2

Possibly relevant options:

- Data enabled - off
- Data roaming - off
- Restrict background data - off - I use skype and imo.im, so it's nice to have them update in background
- Auto-sync data - on
- Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep - always

Comment: "Restrict background data" is only for mobile data AFAIK. For the rest I'm as confused as you are: with "mobile data = off" there should not be a single byte transferred. So the "restrict background data" should not even matter.